# how to give an option multiple values and display those value on separate areas?

Tags: javascript, html

So we have this html form activity and I wanted to give different values to a product and then autofill other parts of the form.

I am hoping that its possible with html and javascript too.

I'm only a student trying to get pass this, thank you.

Code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var val = document.getElementById("Product").value;
  document.getElementById("Unit").innerHTML = val;
}
```

```html
<select name="Product" onchange="myFunction()" id="Product">
  <option selected=""> Choose Product...</option>
  <option value="SM01">Sugar & Moss</option>
  <option value="BF02">Black Fig</option>
  <option value="SR03">Sandalwood Rose</option>
  <option value="GC04">Golden Coast</option>
  <option value="PN05">Piñion</option>
</select>
<textarea id="Unit" readonly=""></textarea>
<textarea id="Code" readonly=""></textarea>
<textarea id="Price" readonly=""></textarea>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want? Also, what have you ever tried?

Comment: Hi! Could you please clarify what is exactly the issue you are facing? I just tried running it and it seems to work as intended. The only thing missing here is setting the values of `Code` and `Price` fields depending on the value of `val` in your JavaScript function (assuming you didn't remove them intentionally to not bloat the post).

Comment: I wanted to give certain textareas 'unit','product code', 'price' a value upon selecting an option. I haven't added other values yet since whenever I try to add another value using separators. it just shows the entire list in one text area. so far i have only tried that.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, using the [`data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) attribute. Those attribute are used to add information to a certain HTML node. With those, you could define what data you want associated with the selected options, and fill the form when the select changes.

Please note that this options is not suited for big form. You wouldn't want to have 20 data field per options. In a case where you might have a greater number of field to fill, I would suggest keeping an object with the differents values and update your fields from that object. I will cover this bellow.

First you need to add the data attribute to your html form. The data attribute starts with the keyword `data` and follow with the name, separeted by a hyphen.

```
<select name="Product" onchange="myFunction()" id="Product">
              <option selected=""> Choose Product...</option>
              <!-- ... -->
              <option value="SR03" data-code="SF23" data-price="19.99">Sandalwood Rose</option>
              <!-- ... -->
            </select>
```

Now that our data is defined, we can capture it on the change event in our Javascript. To acheive that, we can use the `dataset` object on the node

```
function myFunction() {
  const val = document.getElementById("Product").value;
  document.getElementById("Unit").innerHTML = val;
  
  // we use a querySelector to get the selected option
  const selectedOption = document.querySelector('#Product > option[selected] ');

  // from the dataset object, we get value for the selected option
  const price = selectedOption.dataset.price;
  const code = selectedOption.dataset.code;

  // we change the value of the text areas
  document.querySelector('#Code').innerHTML = code;
  document.querySelector('#Price').innerHTML = price;
}
```

If you wish to use an object, you can use the selected option value as a key of the object:

```
function myFunction() {
  // we define the prices and code here.
  const pricesAndCodes = {
     /** ... **/
     SM01: {
        price: '19.99',
        code: 'SF23'
     }
  }

  const val = document.getElementById("Product").value;
  document.getElementById("Unit").innerHTML = val;
  
  // we use a querySelector to get the selected option
  const selectedOption = document.querySelector('#Product > option[selected] ').value;

  

  const selectedPriceAndCodes = pricesAndCodes[selectedOption.value]

  // we change the value of the text areas
  document.querySelector('#Code').innerHTML = selectedPriceAndCodes.code;
  document.querySelector('#Price').innerHTML = selectedPriceAndCodes.price;
}
```

Here are working examples:

Using data attributes:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const val = document.getElementById("Product").value;
  document.getElementById("Unit").innerHTML = val;
  
  // we use a querySelector to get the selected option
  const selectedOption = document.querySelector('#Product > option[value="' + val + '"] ');
  
  // from the dataset object, we get value for the selected option
  const price = selectedOption.dataset.price;
  const code = selectedOption.dataset.code;

  // we change the value of the text areas
  if(price && code ) {
    document.querySelector('#Code').innerHTML = code;
    document.querySelector('#Price').innerHTML = price;
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="Product" onchange="myFunction()" id="Product">
              <option selected=""> Choose Product...</option>
              <option value="SM01" data-code="1" data-price="19.22">Sugar & Moss</option>
              <option value="BF02" data-code="2" data-price="20.22">Black Fig</option>
              <option value="SR03" data-code="3" data-price="21.22">Sandalwood Rose</option>
              <option value="GC04" data-code="4" data-price="23.22">Golden Coast</option>
              <option value="PN05" data-code="5" data-price="40.22">Piñion</option>
            </select>
<textarea id="Unit" readonly=""></textarea>
<textarea id="Code" readonly=""></textarea>
<textarea id="Price" readonly=""></textarea>
```

Using an object

```js
function myFunction() {
  // we define the prices and code here.
  const pricesAndCodes = {
     /** ... **/
     SM01: {
        price: '20.99',
        code: '1'
     },
      BF02: {
        price: '32.99',
        code: '2'
     },
      SR03: {
        price: '23.99',
        code: '3'
     },
      GC04: {
        price: '53.99',
        code: '4'
     },
      PN05: {
        price: '42.99',
        code: '5'
     }
  }

  const val = document.getElementById("Product").value;
  document.getElementById("Unit").innerHTML = val;
  
  const selectedPriceAndCodes = pricesAndCodes[val]

  // we change the value of the text areas
  document.querySelector('#Code').innerHTML = selectedPriceAndCodes.code;
  document.querySelector('#Price').innerHTML = selectedPriceAndCodes.price;
}
```

```html
<select name="Product" onchange="myFunction()" id="Product">
              <option selected=""> Choose Product...</option>
              <option value="SM01" data-code="1" data-price="19.22">Sugar & Moss</option>
              <option value="BF02" data-code="2" data-price="20.22">Black Fig</option>
              <option value="SR03" data-code="3" data-price="21.22">Sandalwood Rose</option>
              <option value="GC04" data-code="4" data-price="23.22">Golden Coast</option>
              <option value="PN05" data-code="5" data-price="40.22">Piñion</option>
            </select>
<textarea id="Unit" readonly=""></textarea>
<textarea id="Code" readonly=""></textarea>
<textarea id="Price" readonly=""></textarea>
```

P.S. You should always rely on your backend to valide the data in the end. It's possible for the user to change the Javascript so never trust what the user is sending you. Good luck !

Comment: Thank you~ I'm practically saved. I've used the second code 'using an object' but I've ran both and it's all working.

Comment: I have additional question, If I want to get the price multiplied to a value from `<input type=number id=quantity>`, how do I do that?